# RF Collection PCB Schematic

Tags: power-supply, pcb, rf, usb, schematics

I usually work with breadboards, but I wanted to use the [P2110B](https://www.powercastco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/P2110B-Datasheet-Rev-3.pdf) from Powercast, and since I couldn't find any breakout boards for it and *desperately* needed some experience with schematics and PCBs, I decided to make my first design in hopes of turning it into a PCB.

The part that scares me about PCBs is that with breadboard if it doesn't work I can just try again, but once you order a PCB that doesn't work **that's it**. So I wanted to make sure that this KiCad schematic was okay before I did anything else.

(Furthermore, I am sorry if I have not used proper conventions while making this schematic, it is my first time and I tried to the best of my ability).

[image]

I made sure that it passed KiCad's electrical tests, so I'll go by and explain what i was attempting:

- The goal of this is to catch RF signals using an antenna and convert them to 5V DC which would be sent through a USB A port.
- The documentation stated how the output current could be increased from 3.3V to 5.5V by applying a resistor of a calculated amount from VSET to GND. The value I got for a 5V output was 720k. (I added a 5V regulator just in case.)
- The documentation also specified a capacitor was required on the VCAP pin to determine the charging and operation cycles of VOUT. I calculated that for an ON period of around ~7 seconds with 5V and 50mA, a 10F supercapacitor was required.
- Lastly, there is an SMA connector near RFIN for the RF supply.

I hope that with that you can make sense of what is most likely a very poor schematic, like stated do go easy on me, this is my first ever attempt at a PCB. I thought I'd start off with something I actually wanted and was also a bit easy.

Comment: Relax. Once you ordered a PCB that doesn't work .... you get out the scalpel. tack wire, solder  and loctite. If you were reasonably close to begin with, it's STILL a hundred times neater and works better than a breadboard. (OTOH if you got a 68-pin IC footprint upside down, it's a mess). If you haven't ordered the PCB yet you can add options, like resistors to +V and/or GND to unused pins, in case you need to tie them high or low, or that extra cap you're not sure about (you don't have to fit it after all!)

Comment: Ouch! I havent soldered anything that small, but I've seen how tiny those legs are and don't think i need to guess that what you described would be difficult haha. Im personally more worried that the connections of the actual pcb are wrong

Comment: The connections to the coax connector imply that the center conductor is grounded, and the shield is connected to the P2110B's RF input - the connector symbol should be flilpped horizontally.

Comment: Why do you have a diode in series with the capacitor on the Vcap pin?

Comment: Putting the output onto a USB A connector implies that you may be a little over-optimistic about the amount of power you're likely to get from this circuit ...

Comment: @PeterBennett just to make sure that no power flowed into the supercapacitor. But if that wouldn't have happened anyway, I can take it off.

Comment: Oh, and @brhans, i know, more of a proof of concept than anything else really. The USB connector just seemed more convenient than test pads